# Node.js and node phantom include jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, phantomjs

My currently code:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
var fs = require('fs');

phantom.create(function(ph) {

  return ph.createPage(function(page) {

    return page.open("http://www.example.com", function(status) {

      page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js', function(err) {

        return page.evaluate(function() {
          return $('#test').value();
        }, function(result) {
          console.log(result)
        });

      });

    });
  });
});
```

I'm trying to include jQuery into the page so everything is fine till I get to `$()` part where I get this error:

> Undefined is not a constructor (evaluating $('#test').value())

If instead of `$('#test').value()` I try for example `document.title` everything works fine tho.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you copied the correct error message it should be:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#test').value()')

Anyway your problem is `.value()` as this is not a function provided by jQuery.
You are probably looking for `.val()` or `.text()`.